# Set a variable in shell from JavaScript (node.js)

Tags: node.js, shell, variables

I've got a script I run like this:

```
node script.js
```

From within script.js, I would like to pass a variable back out to the shell for continued use.

I'll say it again in case you didn't get it the first time: basically, running the JS to come up with a variable, then I want to use that variable for a shell command. I tried looking this up and I didn't have much luck figuring it out. Simply doing console.log(foo=bar) doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell has to cooperate (well, usually -- you could force it to set the variable through gdb/ptrace, but that's very hacky and you could break the shell).
You can output (console.log) the value and the shell can capture it:

```
variable=$(node script.js)
```

or you can output, e.g., `eval`able text that'll set the value and then `eval` it:

```
eval "$(node -e 'console.log("variable=42")')"
echo $variable
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. In my situation, I combined it with IFS to get multiple variables out of the same JS file.

    IFS=,;
    set $(node script.js);
    var1=$1;
    var2=$2;